# Move the tbody of a table up using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a table which will have dozens of rows, but what I would like to do is have only 5 of the rows shown at once. To accomplish this my thought is to set a height on the container of the table and hide overflow and then use `top` or `translateY` or some other method to shift the rows within the `tbody` up or down. Unfortunately I can't seem to get this to work quite right.

Here's my current attempt using transform, this seems to cause issues with the table border and the `tbody` cells are going over the top of the `thead` cells. I also tried a few things using a negative `top` value but couldn't get it to work that way either:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('table tbody').toggleClass('shifted');
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  height:175px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
  thead td {
    background:white;
  }
  tbody.shifted {
    transform:translateY(-145px);
  }
  td {
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:5px;
  }
  
button {
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Heading 1</td>
        <td>Heading 2</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem 1</td>
        <td>Ipsum 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem 2</td>
        <td>Ipsum 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem 3</td>
        <td>Ipsum 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem 4</td>
        <td>Ipsum 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem 5</td>
        <td>Ipsum 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem 6</td>
        <td>Ipsum 6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem 7</td>
        <td>Ipsum 7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem 8</td>
        <td>Ipsum 8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem 9</td>
        <td>Ipsum 9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem 10</td>
        <td>Ipsum 10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<button>Shift table rows</button>
```

Comment: why don' t you just use pagination or tbody scroll with js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of transforming the table, you could just use `:nth-child()` to hide select rows.

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('table tbody').toggleClass('shifted');
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
thead td {
  background: white;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(n+6) {/* 6th row and later */
  display: none;
}
tbody.shifted tr:nth-child(n) {/* override the non-shifted styles */
  display: table-row;
}
tbody.shifted tr:nth-child(-n+5) {/* 5th row and earlier */
  display: none;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Heading 1</td><td>Heading 2</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>Lorem 1</td><td>Ipsum 1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Lorem 2</td><td>Ipsum 2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Lorem 3</td><td>Ipsum 3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Lorem 4</td><td>Ipsum 4</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Lorem 5</td><td>Ipsum 5</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Lorem 6</td><td>Ipsum 6</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Lorem 7</td><td>Ipsum 7</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Lorem 8</td><td>Ipsum 8</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Lorem 9</td><td>Ipsum 9</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Lorem 10</td><td>Ipsum 10</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<button>Shift table rows</button>
```